# Help with induction proof please! For an integer $n, 3$ divides $n^3-n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

Please help with this induction proof!
I am trying to show that for an integer $n, 3$ divides $n^3-n$. I know how to do it for all positive integers, but am not sure how to prove it for 0 or negative integers.

Comment: Show that if $3$ divides $n^3-n$, then $3$ also divides $(-n)^3-(-n)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! You should include more context to your question, namely not just what you want to show and your claim that you can do it for all positive integers, but also your actual proof for all positive integers. Then you can get proper feedback and help.

Comment: Perhaps this is an example of a statement for which induction should only be used to prove it for the sake of learning how to use induction. It should be clear that $3 | n^3-n$ via the factorization $n^3-n = n(n+1)(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Guide to perform induction for non-positive number:

Base case: show that the statement is true for $n=0$.

Induction step: Suppose the statement is true for $n=k$, then show that the statement is true for $n=k-1$ too, that is if $k^3-k$ is divisible by $3$, then show that $(k-1)^3-(k-1)$ is divisible by $3$.

The working should be highly similar to the positive number case.

Hence, if the statement is true for $n=0$, using the induction step, we can conclude that it is true for $n=-1$, $n=-2, \ldots.$

Answer (score 0):

If $n^3-n=3q$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
(n+1)^3-(n+1)&=&(n+1)(n^2+2n+1)-n-1\\
&=&n^3+2n^2+n+n^2+2n+1-n-1\\
&=&(n^3-n)+3n^2+3n
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Prove that $n^3-n$ is divisible by $3$.

**Solution:** Let $f(n)$ denote the statement

$$f(n)=n^3-n$$

**Base Step ($n=1$):**
\begin{align}
f(1) & = 1^3-1 \\
& = 0
\end{align}
$3 | 0 \implies f(1)$ holds.

**Inductive Step $f(k) \to f(k+1)$:** Fix some $k$. Assume that 
$$f(k)=k^3-k$$
holds and is divisible by $3$. To be proved is that
$$f(k+1)=(k+1)^3-(k+1)$$
follows. Beginning with the right-hand side of $f(k+1)$

\begin{align}
(k+1)^3-(k+1) & = k^3+3k^2+3k+1-k-1\\
& = k^3+3k^2+2k \\
& = k^3-k+3k^2+3k \\
& = f(k) + 3(k^2+k)
\end{align}

by the inductive assumption, $3|f(k)$. Clearly, $3|3(k^2+k)$, thereby showing $f(k+1)$ is true, completing the inductive step.

**Conclusion:** By mathematical induction, it is proved that $n^3-n$ is divisible by $3$. $\Box$

Comment: I think it would be clearer to write $(n+1)^2-(n+1)-(n^3-n) = n^3+3n^2+2n-(n^3-n) = 3n^2+3n$ and that is divisible by 3. This way there is no magic rewrite.